# Javascript, how return functions in closures are concatenated with the outer function

Tags: javascript, closures

```
function func() {
  return this == myObject;
}

var boundFunc = func.bind(myObject, "arg1", "arg2");
boundFunc("arg3", "arg4");

Function.prototype.bind = function() {
  var fn = this;
  var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
  var object = args.shift();

  return function() {

    var allArgs = args.concat(Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments))
    return fn.apply(object, allArgs);
  };

}
```

I need some help with the above snippet of code. I think I understand it except for one thing.

I don't understand how this:

```
return function() {

  var allArgs = args.concat(Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments))
  return fn.apply(object, allArgs);
};
```

refers to this:

```
boundFunc("arg3", "arg4");
```

I know that when bind gets called `args` gets the arguments (myObject, arg1, arg2). But I don't understand how `return function()` is referring to `boundfunc` in order to concatenate `arg3` and `arg4` with `args`. Does that make sense? Can anyone shed some light on the subject for me please?

Comment: Well, take a piece of paper and try to evaluate `boundFunc("arg3", "arg4");` manually. Just write down every expression of every statement and try to evaluate them one after another.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what happens if you disassemble the code:

```
var boundFunc = function() {
    var allArgs = ["arg1", "arg2"].concat([].slice.call(arguments))
    return func.apply(myObject, allArgs);
};
```

The arguments in `.bind()` are kept and a proxy function is returned that will call `func` with a combination of the earlier arguments and the new ones that are passed in the call.